# How to use the option ExternalForce in NBodySimulation

Tags: options, simulation

I want to simulate the movement of a small ball on a curved track like the following:
[image]
This is my current code:

```
countTime = 5;
data = NBodySimulation[
   Association["PairwisePotential" -> "Newtonian", 
    "Region" -> StadiumShape[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}, 1.001]], <|
    "Mass" -> Quantity[1, "Kilograms"], 
    "Position" -> Quantity[{-1, -1}, "Meters"], 
    "Velocity" -> Quantity[{1, 0}, "Meters"/"Seconds"]|>, countTime];

Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Line[{{-1, -1}, {1, -1}}], 
   Circle[{1, 0}, 1, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}], Red, PointSize[0.02], 
   Point /@ data[All, "Position", time]}, 
  Axes -> True], {time, $MachineEpsilon, countTime, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Now I want to add **universal gravitation** for this system, and I note the option `"ExternalForce"` maybe can help me in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NBodySimulation.html). But I don't know how to use it. And I didn't get any instructions on how to use this option. If I add it by this code:

```
NBodySimulation[
 Association["PairwisePotential" -> "Newtonian", 
  "Region" -> StadiumShape[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}, 1.001], 
  "ExternalForce" -> Quantity[{0, -9.8}, "Newtons"]], <|
  "Mass" -> Quantity[1, "Kilograms"], 
  "Position" -> Quantity[{-1, -1}, "Meters"], 
  "Velocity" -> Quantity[{1, 0}, "Meters"/"Seconds"]|>, countTime]
```

I will get an error information:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NBodySimulation` is an *Experimental* feature, and it is indeed a bit underdocumented. So I have delved into the source code (which you can do with `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions ``), and I have managed to figure it out. For the sake of simplicity, my examples are with dimensionless quantities.

Basically, `"ExternalForce"` of `"ExternalPotential"` should be functions, which are then applied to state associations (so you can use `#["Position"]`), and which return a force vector (or potential scalar). As far as I have managed to understand the source code, you cannot make external force or external potential be different for the bodies.

###### Auxiliary functions

```
plotResults[data_] := 
  Module[{simTime = data["SimulationTime"]}, 
   Column[{"Equation(s) of motion", 
     TraditionalForm@Column@data["Equations"], 
     Row[Plot[Evaluate@#[[2]], {t, 0, simTime}, ImageSize -> 200, 
         PlotLabel -> #[[1]]] & /@ {{"Position", 
         data[1, "Position", t]}, {"Velocity", 
         data[1, "Velocity", t]}, {"Kinetic energy", 
         data["TotalKineticEnergy", t]}}]}]];

animateResults[data_, reg_] := 
 Manipulate[
  Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Black], reg, Red, PointSize[0.03], 
    Point /@ data[All, "Position", t]}, PlotRange -> Full], {t, 0, 
   data["SimulationTime"]}];
```

#### Free fall with `"ExternalForce"`

```
g = 1;
data = NBodySimulation[
   <|"ExternalForce" -> ({0, -g #["Mass"]} &)|>,
   {<|"Mass" -> 2, "Position" -> {1, 2}, "Velocity" -> {0, 0}|>}, 1];

plotResults[data]
```

[image: ExternalForce]

#### Free fall with `"ExternalPotential"`

```
data = NBodySimulation[
   <|"ExternalPotential" -> ({0, g #["Mass"] #["Position"]} &)|>,
   {<|"Mass" -> 2, "Position" -> {1, 2}, "Velocity" -> {0, 0}|>}, 1];

plotResults[data]
```

[image: ExternalPotential]

#### Ball in a circle

```
reg = Disk[{0, 0}, 5];
data = NBodySimulation[
   <|"ExternalPotential" -> ({0, g #["Mass"] #["Position"]} &),
    "Region" -> reg|>,
   {<|"Mass" -> 2, "Position" -> {1, 2}, "Velocity" -> {0, 0}|>}, 50];

plotResults[data]
```

[image: Circle]

[image: Circle.gif]

#### Ball in a stadium

```
reg = StadiumShape[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}, 1.001];
data = NBodySimulation[
   <|"ExternalPotential" -> ({0, #["Mass"] g #["Position"]} &),
    "Region" -> reg|>,
   {<|"Mass" -> 2, "Position" -> {-1, -1}, "Velocity" -> {2, 0}|>}, 50];

plotResults[data]
```

[image: Stadium]

[image: Stadium.gif]

Comment: Thanks, as your explanation,`"ExternalForce" -> (Quantity[{0, -9.8 #["Mass"] }, "Newtons"] &)` is my after

Comment: I don't know why the little ball sometimes has to [leave its orbit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyXpL.png): `Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoMDn.png"],"Byte"]]]]`

Comment: Region [gets discretized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJMkT.png) internally with ``MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity``. This produces a raggy stadium. Discretize it yourself with a finer mesh, for example: ``"Region" -> BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[StadiumShape[ ... ], MaxCellMeasure -> .001]``. This makes the trajectory a bit smoother.

Comment: Crazy man!! Thanks for the source code dig very very much

Comment: Thank you, but the potential functions you're using are not scalars. What are they supposed to be? It looks like -D[{forceX[r],forceY[r]},r]? If I use what I expect to be a proper scalar potential function (V = mgy) by specifying "ExternalPotential" -> (#["Mass"] Indexed[#["Position"], 2] &), it doesn't work.